# GSAP Draggable with multiple triggers?

Tags: javascript, gsap

```
$(".foo").each(function() {
  Draggable.create(this, {
    trigger: $(this).find(".a4")
  });
  Draggable.create(this, {
    type: 'rotation',
    trigger: $(this).find(".a0, .a2, .a6, .a8"),
    cursor: 'alias'
  });
});
```

If I create 2 draggables, only the last one sticks. Any way to have multiple triggers on the same object?

https://jsfiddle.net/w91nfmdg/

Comment: Possible for you to create a fiddle for this please?